# What words are used to describe the journey of a line on a graph?

Tags: synonyms, mathematics

I am looking for words that describe the lines on graphs, or that are used during the journey of a graph line.
For example, Nadir is the lowest point but are there words for the following:

A. The most common point hit in a continuous graph line.
B. When it levels out.
C. It’s highest point, or highest points named as a group.
D.  Any mirroring in other graphs ( you sometime see then as 4 graphs together about same subject.
E. Any other terms used while graph making.

Comment: Look up “describing graphs” on Google. There are many graph types and a great deal of vocabulary.

Comment: I suggest you restrict the question to a single feature, and if possible provide a diagram or diagrams. Some of these are trivial and any precalculus text should explain. There are also various math forums here but I'm not sure how useful they would be.

Comment: Other terms can include *asymptotes* (where the graph goes to infinity either vertically or horizontally) Smooth (and therefore Continuous or Differentiable) where the next point on the line of the graph can be arrived at by an infinitesimally tiny step from the previous point. Monotonic means the graph always goes up, or down when traversed from left to righ. If a graph isn't monotonic, then it is liable to have one or more *inflection points* where the trend of change over time is reversed. Much of these terms rest heavily on the subject of calculus which provides more detail.

Answer (score 1):

- *The most common point hit in a continuous graph line.* **[Attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor)**, especially in dynamic systems
- *When it levels out.* **[Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau_(mathematics))**
- *It’s highest point, or highest points named as a group.* **[Apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_(geometry))**
- *Any mirroring in other graphs (you sometime see then as 4
  graphs together about same subject).* Do you mean **[symmetry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symmetry)**?
- *Any other terms used while graph making.* See comment by [@Xanne](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/223618/xanne)

Comment: Thank you this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here are several.
Increase, decrease.
High and low.
Sharp > rise / fall.
Flat, constant.
Stable, unstable.